# JSP - filter table by predefined options with DataTables plugin

Tags: jquery, jsp, datatable

I work with web application which uses Java and JSP.
One of JSPs has a table. Table has a column "Fruit", whose possible values are "apple" and "banana". I need to be able to show either only apples, only bananas or all together. For this I will use select HTML element.

The JSP page uses DataTables plug-in for jQuery. I could not find respective information in the DataTables manual.
So my question is - can DataTables provide what I need? If not - is there other libraries for this or should I use pure JQuery/JavaScript?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add custom filters to DataTables. `$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering` is an array of filtering functions. By default, it will be empty. To add a filter, do something like this:

```
 $.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
         function( oSettings, aData, iDataIndex ) {
             var row = oSettings.aoData[iDataIndex].nTr;
             return $(row).hasClass('closed');
         });
```

This filter will return only rows with the class 'closed' (on the tr element). This can obviously be modified to for your needs. Since you're only using a single filter, you can just pop to remove and again show all rows.

```
 $.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.pop();
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer! Unfortunately I was unable to apply your example. But I have found another solution with oTable.fnFilter('valueToFilterBy', columnIndex, );